# Update Related Fields of Subform When Updating Main Form In Ms Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a main form and a continuous subform which is connected to main form using `invoice id, customer name and invoice date`. When I add a new invoice, I select customer in main form and enter data in subform because I allow edits in my subform.

Now if I change customer in main form, customer should also change in subform for the data which I already added. But my subform turns to blank, when I select previous customer it shows the entered data.

I want my subform customer update to newly selected customer in main form. I used some vba code but its not working. The below code I got from a tutorial.

```
Private Sub Customer_Name_AfterUpdate()
With Me.[Sales_Invoice_Detail(its my subform].Form.RecordsetClone
Do Until .EOF
.Edit
!Customer_Name = Me.Customer_Name (This is the Field which i want to update in my subform)
!Invoice_Id = Me.Invoice_Id( it has one to many relationship between forms)
.Update
.MoveNext
Loop
'MsgBox "You Change Customer To " & Customer_Name & "!"
End With
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: You can link the two by the ID or use `.requery` of the subform if it's query based.  How is the form set up, have you used the form wizards linking?

Comment: provide table definition for both forms and the relationship.

Comment: Forms are Linked With Id, Customer Name and Date.  Subform is query based and have two tables.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to read the code once it gets any bigger if you don't indent it properly.

Answer (score 0):

> a continuous subform which is connected to main form using invoice id,
>   customer name and invoice date

Remove customer name and invoice date from the connection (MasterLinkFields/ChildLinkFields). These can be pulled either directly from the parent form or - using a query - from the source of the subform.

Comment: if i remove customer name link, then in my sub form this field will be blank.

Comment: Your _master/child_ links must be between a _primary key_ and the matching _foreign key_.

Comment: Yes you are right. i removed link but now my subform is entering data without selecting customer in main form. do you have any suggestion for that.

Comment: I would disable the subform if a customer is not selected.